# Where to clear the client side cache when using amplify js and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amplifyjs

I have an MVC application. The page I have takes some filter criteria and gets the data from the server and does some other operations on the data. The requirement is that when the page loads, there should be no data filtered but once the user enters some filter criteria and does any operations, on both Ajax calls and page refreshes, the filter criteria needs to be stored and applied.
I'm using amplify.js to store the settings chosen by the user.
I'm storing the filter criteria whenever the user does any refresh/Ajax call.
And on $document.ready, I'm applying the filter criteria again

The problem is that the data does not get cleared. So, when the user launches the application, the filter criteria is being applied.
If I clear the criteria in $document.ready, I lose the data on user operations also.

So, how to differentiate between the Initial page load and the subsequent refresh/redirect/Ajax call?

here is the code to apply filters.

```
var filterData = amplify.store.localStorage(filterKey) ? JSON.parse(amplify.store.localStorage(filterKey)) : defaultFilterData;
applyFilters(filterData);
```

To store the filterData,

```
amplify.store.localStorage(filterKey, ko.mapping.toJSON(filterData));
```

By initial load, I meant that when the application is launched first time. Because the problem I'm facing is that the amplify stores data even when I close the application and relaunch..

Comment: Please, show us some code!

Comment: How do **you** define an "Initial page load"?

Comment: here is the code to apply filters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application is structured, but based on your question I suppose you could set a Session variable, and if it's the first time that the user is acessing your page you clear the localStorage.
TempData would fit in this scenario too, because you could set a variable that will exist just in the first request.

For example:

```
Session["firstRequest"] = true;
```

or

```
TempData["firstRequest"] = true;
```

You can set this variables at Session_OnStart() event, or in your Controller.